# Characterset in H2 database

Tags: java, sql, h2

We use a H2 database on multiple servers around the world. With one turkish customer, we had the issue that suddendly, some SQL queries stopped working.

```
CASE WHEN DEF_COUNT.DEF_CNT İS NULL THEN NULL ELSE     CONCAT(İFNULL(DEF_OUTSTANDING.DEF_OUT_CNT,0),' / ',DEF_COUNT.DEF_CNT) END     DEFICIENCY_QUOTA,
CASE WHEN OBS_COUNT.OBS_CNT İS NULL THEN NULL ELSE     CONCAT(İFNULL(OBS_OUTSTANDING.OBS_OUT_CNT,0),' / ',OBS_COUNT.OBS_CNT) END     OBSERVATION_QUOTA,
CASE WHEN REC_COUNT.REC_CNT İS NULL THEN NULL ELSE     CONCAT(İFNULL(REC_OUTSTANDING.REC_OUT_CNT,0),' / ',REC_COUNT.REC_CNT) END     RECOMMENDATION_QUOTA,
CASE WHEN NCR_COUNT.NCR_CNT İS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(İFNULL(NCR_OUTSTANDING.NCR_OUT_CNT,0),' / ',NCR_COUNT.NCR_CNT) END NON_CONFORMITY_QUOTA,
CASE WHEN OTHERS_COUNT.OTHERS_CNT İS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CONCAT(İFNULL(OTHERS_OUTSTANDING.OTHERS_OUT_CNT,0),' / ',OTHERS_COUNT.OTHERS_CNT) END OTHERS_QUOTA,
```

Searching the log files have revealed the fact, that the Is (the letter I) in some keywords seems to have been replaced with a turkish İ (note the period above the I) and therefore causing syntax errors.

We use a Java implementation and the packages are precompiled builds, so therefore the users couldn't have tampered with the code.

This particular piece of code is placed in our persistence layer and started working fine again once the user switched his system language to English. As mentioned before, the class files are compiler when we build the packages before any release.

Is it possible that H2 somehow changes collations? Please also note that the H2 is on a Server at the customer on hardware that we provide ourselves, so again, no chance of the user tampering with the setup.

Thanks for any pointers

Comment: By any chance the java code UPPER case is used with locale. Like "is".toUpperCase(new Locale("tr"))

Comment: Maybe you used toUpperCase method with Locale in sql generation

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez This should not happen. As I described, the relevant SQL is not being generated on runtime but on compile time when we build the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found the cause of this.

This particulate code snippet was not generated at compile time, but my fellow programmer put this in the runtime and called toUpperCase() on this string causing this issue.